# how to display local date/time in browser?

Tags: node.js, express

I am coding an nodejs express application. The dates are stored in database using the UTC date/time. I'd like to display the date/time in the user's local time zone. how could I implement this?

Thank you in advance.
Richard Xu

Comment: you can use momentjs is a good library to work with dates https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0):

In your template you could do

```
<span data-date-utc="Wed, 25 Apr 2018 18:16:13 UTC"></span>
```

Then use js to render it in the users local time (I'm using jQuery here to extract the date string, then render it back to the page)

```
$('span').text(new Date($('span').attr('data-date-utc')).toLocaleString());
```

You can use any of the [Date Object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in place of `toLocaleString` to render your output however you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) npm package and for more information refer to the [momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/).

```
var utcDate = moment.utc("2018-04-26 10:00:00");
var localDate = moment(utcDate).local();
```

Now you can use the below function to format the date accordingly.

```
localDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```